# Python script with redirected output crashing with no error not in output

Tags: python, bash, cron

I have a python script that runs @reboot on an Ubuntu server. The output for this script is redirected to a log file. The whole cronjob looks like this:

```
@reboot stdbuf -oL python /home/justin/script.py 2> /home/justin/log
```

The "stdbuf" is to stop the output from being buffered until the script is complete and instead write it out immediately to the log file.

The script contains an infinite loop, so it should only be stopping when it crashes. However, when I check the log file that is generated, I see no error message at the end of the file.

Is there something I'm missing here, or maybe a better way to be redirecting all python errors to a file?

Answer (score 0):

Is it better if you set it like this ?

```
@reboot /path/to/stdbuf -oL /path/to/python /home/justin/script.py 2> /home/justin/log
```